# Rails Nested Form Not Saving Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @customer = Customer.new

    if @user.save
      flash.notice = "User '#{@user.email}' was succefully created."
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, customer_attributes: [:id, :company])
  end
end
```

And I have the following User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

And the following Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Finally, here is the form:

```
<%= form_for [@user] do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :customers do |company| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= company.label :company %><br>
      <%= company.text_field :company %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form, I see: `Unpermitted parameters: customers' in the log but it appears that I m indeed permitting it.

Also, I want to show the company name for each user in the show and index views. I'm not sure how to do that.

I remember using the `build` method in the past to get something similar to work but I can't seem to figure it out this time.

Comment: Replace this "<%= f.fields_for :customers do |company| %>" by "<%= f.fields_for :customer do |company| %>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_customer
end
```

your form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  // user fields
  <%= f.fields_for :customer do |customer| %> 
    // customer fields
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also there is not need of @customer = Customer.new in your create method.

Comment: Can I edit your code? You'll be better not using the `@customer` variable imo

Comment: @RichPeck sure but it is has_one relationship so will it make a difference? I mean if you are building multiple associated attributes then a symbol is the way to go but for has_one? :)

Comment: @RichPeck ahh i see you saved an instance variable :)

Comment: @RichPeck it was about variable only or there was something else too?

Comment: Only var - I'm writing a more comprehensive answer to explain things; but yours will get it working for him

Answer (score 8):

Further to `@Mandeep`'s answer, let me give you some further information:

> 1. You need to "build" your associated objects for your form
> 2. You need to process this as per the *association* your model has
> 3. You need to save the attributes as per said association

The way to do this is relatively simple (outlined by `Mandeep`). However, the reason *why* might be a little less obvious:

---

**Build**

First, you need to build your associative association. This is vitally important, primarily because Rails (by virtue of being built on Ruby), is an [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) framework.

Object orientation, without getting into too much detail, means that *everything* you do with Rails is going to be based around objects. In the case of our beloved Rails, it means that every `Model` is an `object`.

By virtue of this fact, the nested model paradigm has to be *built* in Rails whenever you want to create such a form. To do this, you need to use the [`build` methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Auto-generated+methods) - which tell [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) (Rails' [**object** relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)) that you have another associated model / object which you want to populate:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.new #-> initializes "User" object
      @user.build_customer #-> "builds" the associated object
   end
end
```

This gives Rails a set of associated data which it can populate with your form (considering you call the correct methods)

--

**Association**

Second, you need to consider the *association* you have. This is important as singular & multiple associations are handled differently in the "build" process.

You're using a `has_one` relationship, which means you need to use **singular** association names (although you can call the associations whatever you want):

[image]

If you used a `has_many` association, you'd need to use the plural association methods:

[image]

This explains the need to use the `build_customer` method; but also should give you the presidence to use the singular association name for all the methods you need to get this working, namely `fields_for` and `params`:

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :customer do |c| %>
      ...
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @user = User.new user_params
      @user.save
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.permit(:user).permit(:user, :params, customer_attributes: [:x. :y])
   end

end
```

--

**Save**

The above controller code will *save* the attributes you require.

You must understand that passing *nested* attributes means that the model you're sending the associative data to needs to be subordinated to your "main" model. This happens with the `ActiveRecord associations` in your models, as discussed initially.

Hopefully this gives you some more clarity